# Displaying issues in Mozilla and Edge

Tags: css, mozilla, microsoft-edge

```css
.wrapper{
     width: 800px;
     margin: 0 auto;
}
canvas{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.color-picker{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.color-col{
    width:6.6666%;
    min-height: 50px;
    display: inline-flex;
 display: -webkit-inline-flex;
}
```

```html
 <table class="color-picker">
                     <tr>
                    <td class="text-center ">
                        <h1 class="mar50">GIFT BOX COLOUR</h1>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>

                    <td class="color-col gift-color" onclick="giftColourClick('0')"
                        style="background-color:#f4ed94">
                    </td>
                    <td class="color-col gift-color" onclick="giftColourClick('1')"
                        style="background-color:#eef5db">
                    </td>
                    <td class="color-col gift-color" onclick="giftColourClick('2')"
                        style="background-color:#c7efcf">
                    </td>
                    <td class="color-col gift-color" onclick="giftColourClick('3')"
                        style="background-color:#a9d18e">
                    </td>
                    <td class="color-col gift-color" onclick="giftColourClick('4')"
                        style="background-color:#78cbcf">
                    </td>
                    <td class="color-col gift-color" onclick="giftColourClick('5')"
                        style="background-color:#5eb3d6">
                    </td>
                    <td class="color-col gift-color" onclick="giftColourClick('6')"
                        style="background-color:#bdd7ee">
                    </td>
                    <td class="color-col gift-color" onclick="giftColourClick('7')"
                        style="background-color:#af90a9">
                    </td>
                    <td class="color-col gift-color" onclick="giftColourClick('8')"
                        style="background-color:#ffc7df">
                    </td>
                    <td class="color-col gift-color" onclick="giftColourClick('9')"
                        style="background-color:#ff5a5f">
                    </td>
                    <td class="color-col gift-color" onclick="giftColourClick('10')"
                        style="background-color:#e88873">
                    </td>
                    <td class="color-col gift-color" onclick="giftColourClick('11')"
                        style="background-color:#c4c4c4">
                    </td>
                    <td class="color-col gift-color" onclick="giftColourClick('12')"
                        style="background-color:#ffffff">
                    </td>
                    <td class="color-col gift-color" onclick="giftColourClick('13')"
                        style="background-color:#6e6460">
                    </td>
                    <td class="color-col gift-color" onclick="giftColourClick('14')"
                        style="background-color:#464647">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="15">
                        <input class="mar50" id="gift-range" onchange="giftRangeChange(this.value)" type="range" min="0" max="14"  value="14"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr >
                    <td class="text-center">
                        <h1 class="mar50">RIBBON COLOUR</h1>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>

                    <td class="color-col ribbon-color" onclick="ribbonColourClick('0')"
                        style="background-color:#f4ed94">
                    </td>
                    <td class="color-col ribbon-color" onclick="ribbonColourClick('1')"
                        style="background-color:#eef5db">
                    </td>
                    <td class="color-col ribbon-color" onclick="ribbonColourClick('2')"
                        style="background-color:#c7efcf">
                    </td>
                    <td class="color-col ribbon-color" onclick="ribbonColourClick('3')"
                        style="background-color:#a9d18e">
                    </td>
                    <td class="color-col ribbon-color" onclick="ribbonColourClick('4')"
                        style="background-color:#78cbcf">
                    </td>
                    <td class="color-col ribbon-color" onclick="ribbonColourClick('5')"
                        style="background-color:#5eb3d6">
                    </td>
                    <td class="color-col ribbon-color" onclick="ribbonColourClick('6')"
                        style="background-color:#bdd7ee">
                    </td>
                    <td class="color-col ribbon-color" onclick="ribbonColourClick('7')"
                        style="background-color:#af90a9">
                    </td>
                    <td class="color-col ribbon-color" onclick="ribbonColourClick('8')"
                        style="background-color:#ffc7df">
                    </td>
                    <td class="color-col ribbon-color" onclick="ribbonColourClick('9')"
                        style="background-color:#ff5a5f">
                    </td>
                    <td class="color-col ribbon-color" onclick="ribbonColourClick('10')"
                        style="background-color:#e88873">
                    </td>
                    <td class="color-col ribbon-color" onclick="ribbonColourClick('11')"
                        style="background-color:#c4c4c4">
                    </td>
                    <td class="color-col ribbon-color" onclick="ribbonColourClick('12')"
                        style="background-color:#ffffff">
                    </td>
                         <td class="color-col ribbon-color" onclick="ribbonColourClick('13')"
                        style="background-color:#6e6460">
                    </td>
                    <td class="color-col ribbon-color" onclick="ribbonColourClick('14')"
                        style="background-color:#464647">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="15">
                        <input class="mar50" id="ribbon-range" onchange="ribbonRangeChange(this.value)" type="range" min="0" max="14"  value="9"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

I made an [animation](http://utilaje-neamt.ro/demo/) using html canvas and a colour picker from where you can change the two colours of the animation but after a lot of fixes I saw that are some differences between browsers. If in chrome everything is perfect in Mozilla and Edge the black colour dropped one place.

Any suggestions how I can fix that?

[demo](http://utilaje-neamt.ro/demo/)

Comment: Stack Overflow is not your personal debugger. We're trying to build a repository of good Q&As that will help people in the future. You must include a [mcve] in your question.

Comment: Sorry if I create that impression. I stayed a lot and searching for a solution before I asked this and I thought that maybe someone can help me with this problem because have this issue too.

Answer (score 0):

Try a display:block and float:left on .color-col. It worked on Mozilla/Mac and Edge to.

Comment: Just trying that but not working, Also if I change the attribute for display the colours will be displayed vertically, Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.color-col{
    width:6.66666666667%;
    min-height: 50px;
 float:left; // Edge
 display:inline-table; // Chrome 
 display: -webkit-inline-table; // Safari
 display:-moz-box; //Mozilla
 }
```

This changes worked for me and fixed the displaying issues.